# Having issues building a rails query that includes three associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have three models I'm working with: `User`, `Deal`, and `Investment`.

**User**

```
User has many :deals
User has many :investments
```

**Deal**

```
Deal has many :investments
Deal belongs to :user
```

**Investment**

```
Investment belongs to :user
Investment belongs to :deal
```

(these are the only associations I have set up between these models)

Lets say I have a User record 'u', and Deal has an attribute called `funding_type_id`.

I want to find all investments made by user 'u' where the `investment.deal.funding_type_id == 3`.

Or to be more clear: Investments are made on a deal by a user. I was the set of investments made by user 'u' on deals who's funding type id is 3.

I posted this awhile ago, but didn't receive any successful responses. I've made several attempts on my own since then, but all have been met with failure, so I'm back to SO. Hopefully I explained my question clearly. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**: My bad, misread the question -- early morning after a late night :)

Try this instead:

```
investments = Investments.joins(:deal).where(user_id: u.id, deals: { funding_type_id: 3 })
```

That should generate the following SQL (subbing in `1` for `u.id`):

```
SELECT "investments".* FROM "investments"
  INNER JOIN "deals" ON "deals"."id" = "investments"."deal_id"
  WHERE "investments"."id" = 1 AND "deals"."funding_type_id" = 3
```

Which should give you the rows you want.

---

If you set up a `has_many :through` association (see the [Association Basics guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association)) between `User` and `Deal`, you can directly access all the deals belonging to a user:

```
# user.rb
has_many :deals, through: :investments
```

You can then get all the deal for a particular user using:

```
user_deals = User.deals
```

You can optionally put a `where` condition on that to limit it the way you want. Where `u` is the user you want the deals for:

```
deals = u.deals.where(funding_type_id: 3)
```

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear with my question. I'm not interested in getting deals, I just want investments. Investments are made on a deal by a user. I was the set of investments made by user 'u' on deals who's funding type id is 3.

Comment: *I want the set of investments made by user 'u' on deals who's funding type id is 3.